# Ceiling fan old wiring only reds and blacks connected

Tags: electrical

Need some help wiring.

Should I use a three way switch here or 4 way like the old switch.

Switch one had red and black connected  to switch with neutral connected in box.

Switch 2 has two black wires connected with neutrals connected in box.

I don't really need switch two if it's problematic.

Pics below.

Thanks
[image][image]

Comment: any switch with only two wires is not (or does not need to be)  "3 way" or "4 way". (Its not entirely clear what the switches do or what you are asking).  You may want to say where in the world  you are as sometimes terminology varies..

Comment: How many switches control the fan?

Comment: It seems unlikely that this is what we call a "4-way".  The mere fact of having four backstabs does not mean that.  A true 4-way can be used as a simple switch, but it's a waste of an expensive 4-way.  Regardless, that switch is now destined for the trash can - backstabs can't be used twice (the spring mechanism is damaged by any method of extraction), and that one doesn't have screws.